Converting ZPL commands to byte string for QR code Printing
This requirement is for an Appian integration with Zebra printer. I am trying to use an Appian plug in to print QR codes/Bar codes to Zebra printer.
One of the input parameters for the printer is labelString, which is mentioned as a "Sequence of ZBL commands converted to byte string". I am checking online how to convert the ZPL commands to byte string but no luck so far.
This is the command I want to convert to a byte string.
^XA
^FO40,30^A0,40^FD${partId}^FS
^FO50,80^BY3^BCN,60,,,,A^FD${partId}^FS
^XZ 

Instead of a byte string, is it possible to send ZPL commands as text?

Do you send the commands directly to the printer?

I am using a plugin to send the commands to the zebra printer. https://community.appian.com/b/appmarket/posts/zebra-printer-integrator
Inputs: printerIP, rawPortNumber and labelString (Byte string of ZBL commands)
Prerequisites:
Firewall between the Appian hosted machine and printer should be open
Printer's raw port should be exposed to the integration
Sequence of ZBL commands should be converted to byte string for the input parameter.
